# Jupyter Notebook Low CPU Usage

Tags: python, process, jupyter-notebook

I have noticed that some cells take a long time to finish executing on my Jupyter Notebooks. When looking in the task manager, I see that the python process is only using up to about 4% of the CPU. I am using Python 3.6.2

I am on Windows but am using the "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" terminal to launch the Jupyter notebook (maybe this helps). The processor is a Core i7 and the process is not using up all available RAM so it isn't a Swap memory problem.

Basically, why is it being "throttled" like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: So, what tasks? IO task?

Comment: Operations on a Pandas dataframe, like dataframe.apply() etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a public jupyter-notebook, it runs on the host machine and not yours.

Read this:
https://mk-minchul.github.io/JupyterServer/